# Can't lower volume gradually

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a kind of a project in Unity and it's basically just a small area where you can walk and interact with it. In the area, there is a noisy driving car. I wrote a code so the player will hear the volume only when he get's closer and as close he gets to the car, so the player hears it louder. The code works just fine, the problem is I want the volume to get lower gradually when the player gets closer to the car. I have no idea how to do it (maybe somehow using a for loop). Here is the code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SoundZone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource source;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (transform.position.z >= 316)
            source.volume = 0;

        if (transform.position.z < 316)
            source.volume = 0.09f;

        if (transform.position.z < 309)
            source.volume = 0.21f;

        if (transform.position.z < 300)
            source.volume = 0.42f;

        if (transform.position.z < 291)
            source.volume = 0.57f;

        if (transform.position.z < 278)
            source.volume = 0.74f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't bother with such tricks. Use an [Audio Source](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html) (the car) along with a [Audio Listener](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioListener.html) (the player character)

Comment: *"I want the volume to get lower gradually when the player gets closer to the car"* The opposite rather?

Comment: I mean I want a smooth increase of the volume slider.

Comment: Then, you definitely want an Audio Listener, this works pretty well and can generate nice effects automatically, such as doppler if the audio source is moving to or from the listener

Comment: You can dynamically add reverberation to the listener too, if, in example, the character enters a church, a bathroom and so on...

Comment: I do have an audio listener. I will screen record it so you will understand what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an AudioListener Component on the player and an AudioSource Component on the car, it should lower the volume automatically when you move away. But if this isn't enough, you can calculate a volume based on the distance between the player and the car.

```
private AudioSource source;
private Transform car;
private Transform player;
[SerializeField] private float maxDistance;

private void Update()
{
    source.volume = CalculateVolume();
}

private float CalculateVolume()
{
    return 1 - Mathf.Clamp01(Vector3.Distance(player.position, car.position) / maxDistance);
}
```